# Azure Data Factory - how to use pipeline parameter in data flow activity to filter results

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a following problem. I've created my ADF pipeline. It consists of multiple activities. One of those is Data flow activity. I am passing pipeline parameter to Data flow activity (it is called Environment).
In my Data flow activity I have a Filter transformation. I would like to filter results from the previous transformation based on Environment parameter. I tried to add Filter transformation with the following expression:

```
iif(instr(current_url, $Environment) > 0, true(), false())
```

After trying to debug I am receiving following error:
`Column 'dev' used in expression is unavailable or invalid`

'dev' is the value of $Environment variable.

When I used static string (e.g. 'dev') in the expression everything works as expected.

Can you guide me please how I can use this parameter in the expression in Filter transformation?

I also tried to add Derived Column transformation but it also didn't help. The error message was very similar.

I tried to use other parameters that are available in data flow activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You will get the above error when you check the **Expression** checkbox in the in the dataflow activity.

The expression is needed when you are giving an expression and when it is giving the results like integer or date. When you are using `string` type parameter, it's not needed. So, uncheck that checkbox to overcome the error.

[image]

**My sample input data:**

```
Id,Name,current_url,Age
1,Rakesh,development,23
2,Laddu,String,24
3,Virat,de,34
4,MSD,dev,42
5,Starc,Test,33
6,P Hughes,devon,35
```

I have stored `dev` in a string variable and passed it to dataflow parameter like above. I have used the same expression as yours in the filter expression and you can see I got expected results in the sink file when I removed the checkbox.

**Output:**

[image]